# Swift member wise initializer doesn't include parameters with default constant properties

Tags: swift

### Case 1

```
struct User {
  let name: String
  let age: Int
}
```

Available member-wise initializer: `User(name: String, age: Int)`

### Case 2

```
struct User {
  let name: String
  let age = 1
}
```

Available member-wise initializer: `User(name: String)`

### Case 3

```swift
struct User {
  let name: String
  var age = 1
}
```

Available member-wise initializers:

- `User(name: String)`
- `User(name: String, age: Int)`

### Issue

In case 2, there is no-way to set the value for property `age` unless you create an instance of the struct as a variable.

Is this by design? Or is this a limitation in the member-wise initializer for Swift?

Comment: Yes, this is *by design*. A constant can be set only once, that’s the goal of a **constant**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is by design. `age` is a constant here and can only be set one time. If you want a default value for a constant, you write an initializer.

```
struct User {
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int = 1) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I thought SE-0242 in Swift 5.1 allowed for all the behaviors in your code snippet above while allowing for default values for constant properties. Looks like I am wrong.

Comment: SE-0242 just handled `var` properties. Assigned `let` properties are considered constants to the type. It is worth reconsidering whether you really need `let` for things that can be set (even in an init). Remember that structs are value types, so using `var` does not generate shared mutable state. In Swift, using `var` properties on structs doesn't carry the baggage that mutable classes create. (This is an area of some debate, but I think it's worth thinking about carefully.)